# storing previous PHP array elements

Tags: php, arrays, caching

Im doing some excercises on array, Im quite inquisitive to know will i be able to do the below that i have mentioned

i have a function like below

```
function test1($array) { 

    $arr[] = array('list' => 
             array(1, 1, 1));
    return $arr; 
}
```

i get a output like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) )
```

all i want to do is

now i will modify the the above function **test1** like below

```
function test1($array) { 

    $arr[] = array('list' => 
             array(2, 2, 2));
    return $arr; 
}
```

is there any possibility for me to get a output like this...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 ) ) )
```

this is all about storing the previous result and the new one as well

thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you using the $array parameter? My first thought is using a reference to make sure you are changing the existing array. You would have to write 'function test1(&$array) { ... }' but you have to use $array inside the function. I would need more information (more code) for a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you will name your functions, but you can add more entries to an array easily. Be sure to use the array parameter you pass into your `test` function. See below:

```
function test1($arr) { 
    $arr[] = array('list' => 
             array(1, 1, 1));
    return $arr; 
}

function test2($arr) { 
    $arr[] = array('list' => 
             array(2, 2, 2));
    return $arr; 
}


$array = array();

$array = test1($array);
$array = test2($array);

print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but... i dont want to use two functions... all i need is once i modified the function through its element... i want the new elements and the previous set of elements both... is there anyway to do it... one friend told me about a static array but im not familier with that

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your question. I made a demo I'd like you to try: http://tehplayground.com/#mJRysqAnx Please clarify if this is going in the direction you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the original array in, but not actually using it in the function.

```
function test1($array) { 

    $array[] = array('list' => 
             array(2, 2, 2));
    return $array; 
}
```

That will take the array, add a new key that will be another array and populate it.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to do:

first your array:

```
$arr[] = array('list'=>array(1, 1, 1));
```

To modify use:

```
$arr[] = array('list'=>array(2, 2, 2);
```

Final result will be:

```
$arr[] = array('list'=>array(1, 1, 1),'list'=>array(2, 2, 2));
```